# Android failed to launch test, strange run configuration setup behavior

Tags: android

This site is so great I've gone about 3 months of doing Android dev without ever having to post, but alas I knew that wouldn't last forever...

I've seen a few posts similar to my problem, but not quite.  I have an Android project I've been developing over past couple of months, was cruising along just fine, including being able to run Android JUnit Tests on some of my stuff.

Then Eclipse went south on me, rendering my project useless, so I had to recreate my Android project, using the existing, via the "Create project from existing source" option, which I've used many times before.

And my new project runs just fun, both in the debugger and on my Android device.  But my tests no longer run. When I run them I get these two log entries in the Java console and no DDMS logcat entries that give me any more details.

I haven't changed my AndroidManifest file from when it was working, it has the proper entries, i.e.:

```
  <instrumentation android:label="myapp" android:targetPackage="com.myapp" android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"></instrumentation>
```

And also:

```
    <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
```

On the Run Configurations sheet (with Test/Target/Common tabs) the Test tab is acting strange. I have selected the "Run a Single Test" radio; Project is set to my project, and Test class to my test class, but when I click the "Search" button next to Test class entry, the Test Selection list is completely empty.  Instrumentation Runner is set to android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.

I don't remember looking at the run configuration too deeply before, in my original project the test setup was pretty quick and worked the first time.

I reviewed 4-5 similar posts, but solutions there didn't solve my issue.  Has anyone else seen this behavior?  Any clues/suggestions?

Comment: I posted a possible solution over here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15570695/1977828 Maybe this helps you too.