# Junit 4 runner in android test project "Sample Project"

Tags: java, android, junit

Provide me Android sample test project with only 2-3 java files,by using JUnit 4.
I was trying to do this.

My main test file.

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
SimpleMathTest.class
// add other classes here (comma separated)
})
public class TestSuite {
}
```

and I made another test file as JUnit 4 that is

```
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
public class SimpleMathTest {
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
    }
    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
    }
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    }
    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    }
}
```

but at the time of execution Error displays:

> SampleTest: Failed to launch test

please give me some solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The following steps worked for me:

1. Create new JUnit (and NOT "Android Junit Test") Testconfiguration: [image]
2. Add a new test launcher: [image]
3. Choose the following launcher: [image]

With this configuration I can run my unit tests. They run on the pc and not on the phone. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any @Test methods.

Add:

```
@Test
public void test()  {
    //Test code here
}
```